# Не собирается проект в CMake при смене порядка включения субдеррикторий в CMakeLists

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Имеется основной CMakelists

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(my_math_lib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(parse_stream_lib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(calculator)
```

и симейк листы субдеррикторий:

my_math_lib:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)

PROJECT(my_math)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include/my_math)

SET(HEADER_FILES
    include/my_math/my_math.h)

SET(SOURCE_FILES
    src/my_math.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY(my_math STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

SET(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)
```

parse_stream_lib:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)

PROJECT(parse_stream)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${my_math_INCLUDE_DIRS})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include/parse_stream)

SET(HEADER_FILES
    include/parse_stream/parse_stream.h)

SET(SOURCE_FILES
    src/parse_stream.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY(parse_stream STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

SET(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(parse_stream my_math)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(parse_stream my_math)
```

calculator:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)

PROJECT(calculator)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${parse_stream_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(HEADER_FILES)

SET(SOURCE_FILES
    src/calculator_main.cpp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(calculator ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(calculator parse_stream)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(calculator parse_stream)
```

calculator зависит от parse_stream, a parse_stream зависит от my_math.

Проект собирается и все работает, но как только я изменю порядок субдеррикторий в основном  CMakeLists например сделаю :

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(parse_stream_lib)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(my_math_lib) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(calculator)
```

то проект уже не собирается т.к. parse_stream не видит my_math.

Как исправить данную проблему? т.к. при большом проекте будет сложно и займет много времени  выстраивать порядок субдирректорий по порядку их зависимостей

Comment: То есть, Вы хотите, что бы cmake за Вас угадал зависимости между Вашими проектами?

Comment: @KoVadim так в этом и заключается вопрос как правильно оформить cmakelists чтобы каждый файл знал свои зависимости. Я пишу в parse_steam  к примеру                  
    ADD_DEPENDENCIES(parse_stream my_math)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(parse_stream my_math)    но он все равно не видит my_math

Comment: Вам обязательно иметь `project()` в каждой из субдиректорий?

Comment: @arrowd Ну да, каждая библиотека идет как отдельный проект же и потом использую     ${PROJECT_NAME}     вместо фактического названия проекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему помогла решить статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/330902/ 
А именно 4 совет, который говорит что нужно использовать target_include_directories вместо include_directories для добавления путей поиска заголовков, от которых зависит цель.

И проект начинает собираться нормально независимо от порядкя субдеррикторий.
Так же в этой статье в 4 совете имеется ссылка на хорошую презентацию о современном использовании CMake, которая будет полезна для дальнейшей работы с CMake.